# how to show validate message in form in angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2, angular2-routing

I am trying to show validate message in form in angular 2 ? I am getting this error

**Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined**

I added these lines

```
 <div *ngIf="username.hasError('required') && username.touched" 
           class="error-box"> username is required</div>    
       <div *ngIf="username.hasError('minlength') && username.touched" 
           class="error-box"> Minimum password length is 8!</div>
```

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/slhySWT0mJXkloGK1kfO?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
<ion-input type="text" ngControl="username" #username="ngForm"></ion-input>
```

```
 <div *ngIf="username.errors?.required && username.touched" 
           class="error-box"> username is required</div>    
       <div *ngIf="username.errors?.minlength && username.touched" 
           class="error-box"> Minimum password length is 8!</div>
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/U44UYvz92RJYgdnPOnpk?p=preview)

Comment: this is elvis (`?`) operator, this prevents throwing error when variable is undefined

Comment: Sorry, wrong position. `errors` can be `null`, `username` not. And yes, like @PardeepJain mentioned this is to avoid error messages when `errors` is `null`. `?.` is called safe-navigation or Elvis operator which only evaluates the expression after `?.` when the part before is not `null`

Comment: Also some way is necessary to make `username` available. I updated my answer (adding `#username="ngForm"` or what @yurzui explained in his answer)