# How to get a single form field validity in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

NOTE: this is **not** the same question as my other question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356330/how-to-use-pattern-validation-in-angular-2-based-on-ngmodel-template-model-driv

This is my code (Angular 2 rc2 app with deprecated forms):

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
    <input id="inputControlX" ngControl="inputControlX" pattern="abcd">
    {{inputControlX.valid}}
</form>
```

inputControlX **is validated correctly** (ng-invalid class is added to the input).
However when I add

```
 {{inputControlX.valid}}
```

or

```
{{myForm.inputControlX.valid}}
```

or

```
{{ngForm.inputControlX.valid}}
```

I keep getting an error: **can't read property valid of undefined**.
On the other hand adding (as in [this answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428715/how-to-show-validate-message-in-form-in-angular-2)) **#inputControlX="ngForm"**, makes it work (even without ngControl)

**Why is this necessary?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Elvis` operator / `ngIf` directive here, Because when angular tries to evaluate binding of the page, `myForm` object haven't initialized yet. So while evaluating `myForm.inputControlX.valid` expression, `myForm` object isn't defined that time, so it throws an error.

```
{{myForm?.inputControlX?.valid}}
//OR    
<span *ngIf="myForm"> {{myForm.inputControlX.valid}}</span>
```

Comment: thank for the answer. can you please clarify why wirh #tempvar works? after that I'll accept the answer

Comment: You mean to say, linked answer?

Comment: @when you use `#tempvar="ngForm"` angular internally creates an form object & put all the fields inside a that form object which has `ngModel` directive.. and all the validation property are available on each form level object, you can also refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28569650/2435473) of Angular1, the basic fundamental is the same

Comment: @dragonmnl let me know if you need anything else?

Comment: thanks for the further explanations. answer accepted