# EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined rc4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a really beginner question. I am updating m project from beta17 to rc4. I am continuously getting exception: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasError' of undefined`. I assume that I am misusing FromControl and FormGroup.

I am following: http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/

I have added plnkr, it is a bit spaghetti there.
https://plnkr.co/edit/HJaJfAeLfvllAbKdGMkR?p=preview

Thanks a lot

Comment: Post your systemjs.config.js and your package.json. inspecting the actual files you are using will help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, have added them into plnkr

Comment: since updating I am sure you have made changes to you system.config and package.json... have you attempted a simple npm install since the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was really stupid mistake of mine. It supposed to be in @Input().

```
@Input() formControl: FormControl;
```

Sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your plunker I am getting an rxjs error... according to the [io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) you should be mapped directly to it from you systemjs.config.js, which looks something like this

```
  var map = {
'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
'@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'  <--------------------HERE!
 };
 // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
 var packages = {
'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },  <---------------AND HERE!
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
 };
```

I am not a form expert, however the io also covers the new form syntax [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms-deprecated.html)

**EDIT**

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37428715/how-to-show-validate-message-in-form-in-angular-2) post also looks to be similar to what you are experiencing. Which also points toward your syntax possibly being wrong with your form.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just added plnkr in order to avoid putting all the code here. On my machine do not have issue with systemjs.config or with running. The exception accrues, because base class do not know the assigning controller.